# ComplexHeatMap - order rows by order column in underlying dataset, but do not show order column in final heatmap

Tags: r, heatmap, bioconductor

I want to order a Complexheatmap of 4 x heatmaps joined together by a row order which is contained in the 'Order' column of the underlying dataset, however I do not want the order column/data visible in the final graphic.
In effect I want the rows to be the same top to bottom as in this data example, G,Y,K,Z,P,L,V,B,W,O,S,R,X,T (top to bottom),
however when I run my code the row order changes to (top to bottom)
T,K,Z,G,L,V,B,P,Y,S,R,X,O

This is the data -

Name,# V,# O,# I,# S,# R,# E,% W,Order
G,348,0,287,371,392,304,75.522727,1
Y,140,0,85,144,180,103,75.886364,2
K,256,0,197,273,300,214,79.068182,5
Z,225,80,166,238,269,183,80.454545,6
P,174,0,113,183,218,132,82.136364,7
L,170,0,108,176,213,129,75.522727,8
V,170,20,108,176,213,129,80.272727,9
B,167,0,106,171,210,127,3.818182,10
W,167,90,106,171,210,127,100,12
O,12,0,79,12,54,39,80.5,13
S,6,30,77,6,48,35,59.5,14
R,6,0,79,6,49,36,80.454545,15
X,2,50,73,2,45,32,59.772727,19
T,268,0,207,281,311,227,80.522727,20

This is the code -

```
    library("ComplexHeatmap", lib.loc="C:/Users/q805269/Documents/R/R-3.5.1/library")
    library("RColorBrewer", lib.loc="C:/Users/q805269/Documents/R/R-3.5.1/library")
    library("circlize", lib.loc="C:/Users/q805269/Documents/R/R-3.5.1/library")
    library("crayon", lib.loc="C:/Users/q805269/Documents/R/R-3.5.1/library")
    library("pillar", lib.loc="C:/Users/q805269/Documents/R/R-3.5.1/library")
    library("dplyr", lib.loc="C:/Users/q805269/Documents/R/R-3.5.1/library")

    colnames(dataset)[1] <- c("Name") 
    row.names(dataset) <- dataset$"Name"  
    merged<-dataset
    merged1<-select(merged, "# I","# S","# R","# E")

    max_merged1<-as.numeric(max(merged1$"# I"))
    max_merged2<-as.numeric(max(merged1$"# S"))
    max_merged3<-as.numeric(max(merged1$"# R"))
    max_merged4<-as.numeric(max(merged1$"# E"))
    max_merged<-as.numeric(max(max_merged2, max_merged1, max_merged3, max_merged4))

    rc3<-max_merged==0

    if(rc3 == "TRUE") max_merged<-10 else max_merged

    mergedvc<-select(merged, "# V") 
    max_mergedvc<-as.numeric(max(mergedvc$"# V")) 
    rc2<-max_mergedvc==0

    if(rc2 == "TRUE") max_mergedvc<-10 else max_mergedvc

    mergedwst <- select(merged, "% W")  
    max_mergedwst <- as.numeric(max(mergedwst$"% W")) 
    rc1 <- max_mergedwst==0

    if(rc1 == "TRUE") max_mergedwst<-10 else max_mergedwst

    mergedord<-select(merged, "# O")
    max_mergedord<-as.numeric(max(mergedord$"# O"))
    rc<-max_mergedord==0

    if(rc == "TRUE") max_mergedord<-10 else max_mergedord

    merged2<-as.matrix(merged1)
    mergedvc2<-as.matrix(mergedvc)
    mergedwst2<-as.matrix(mergedwst)
    mergedord2<-as.matrix(mergedord)

    ht_global_opt(heatmap_legend_title_gp = gpar(fontsize = 6, fontface = "bold"), 
                  heatmap_legend_labels_gp = gpar(fontsize = 6), heatmap_column_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 6))


    ht1<-Heatmap(merged2, 
            show_row_dend = FALSE,
            show_column_dend = FALSE,
            show_row_names = FALSE,
            column_names_side = "top",
            column_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 8),
                name = "# I,# E,# S,# R", 
                cell_fun = function(j, i, x, y, width, height, fill) 
            {
              grid.text(sprintf("%.0f", merged2[i, j]), x, y, gp = gpar(fontsize = 8))
            },
            col = colorRamp2(c(0, max_merged), c(rgb(200/255, 202/255, 201/255),rgb(116/255, 122/255, 119/255))))

    ht2<-Heatmap(mergedvc2, 
            show_row_dend = FALSE,
            show_column_dend = FALSE,
            row_names_side = "left",
            column_names_side = "top",
            column_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 8),
            row_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 8),
                name = "# V", 
                cell_fun = function(j, i, x, y, width, height, fill) 
            {
              grid.text(sprintf("%.0f", mergedvc2[i, j]), x, y, 
                        gp = gpar(fontsize = 8))
            },
            col = colorRamp2(c(0, max_mergedvc), 
                             c(rgb(185/255, 221/255, 141/255),
                               rgb(119/255, 188/255, 31/255))))

    ht3<-Heatmap(mergedwst2, 
    show_row_dend = FALSE,
    show_column_dend = FALSE,
    show_row_names = FALSE,
    column_names_side = "top",
    column_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 8),
        name = "% W", cell_fun = function(j, i, x, y, width, height, fill) 
    {
      grid.text(sprintf("%.0f", mergedwst2[i, j]), x, y, gp = gpar(fontsize = 8))
    },
    col = colorRamp2(c(0,max_mergedwst), c( rgb(236/255, 154/255, 169/255),rgb(217/255, 59/255, 86/255))))

    ht4<-Heatmap(mergedord2, 
    show_row_dend = FALSE,
    show_column_dend = FALSE,
    show_row_names = FALSE,
    column_names_side = "top",
    column_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 8),      
        name = "# O", cell_fun = function(j, i, x, y, width, height, fill) {
          grid.text(sprintf("%.0f", mergedord2[i, j]), x, y, 
                    gp = gpar(fontsize = 8))
    },  
    col = colorRamp2(c(0,max_mergedord), 
                     c(rgb(255/255, 207/255, 176/255), 
                       rgb(255/255, 108/255, 12/255))))

    ht_list<-ht2+ht4+ht1+ht3

    draw(ht_list, gap = unit(0, "cm"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Got it!
```

Basically add

```
    cluster_rows = FALSE, 
    cluster_columns = FALSE,



       colnames(dataset)[1] <- c("Name")


       row.names(dataset) <- dataset$"Name"

       merged<-dataset


       merged1<-select(merged, "# I","# S","# R","# E")


       max_merged1<-as.numeric(max(merged1$"# I"))
       max_merged2<-as.numeric(max(merged1$"# S"))
       max_merged3<-as.numeric(max(merged1$"# R"))
       max_merged4<-as.numeric(max(merged1$"# E"))
       max_merged<-as.numeric(max(max_merged2,max_merged1,max_merged3,max_merged4))

       rc3<-max_merged==0

       if(rc3 == "TRUE") max_merged<-10 else max_merged



       mergedvc<-select(merged, "# V")

       max_mergedvc<-as.numeric(max(mergedvc$"# V"))

       rc2<-max_mergedvc==0

       if(rc2 == "TRUE") max_mergedvc<-10 else max_mergedvc



       mergedwst<-select(merged, "% W")

       max_mergedwst<-as.numeric(max(mergedwst$"% W"))

       rc1<-max_mergedwst==0

       if(rc1 == "TRUE") max_mergedwst<-10 else max_mergedwst



       mergedord<-select(merged, "# O")

       max_mergedord<-as.numeric(max(mergedord$"# O"))

       rc<-max_mergedord==0

       if(rc == "TRUE") max_mergedord<-10 else max_mergedord


       merged2<-as.matrix(merged1)
       mergedvc2<-as.matrix(mergedvc)
       mergedwst2<-as.matrix(mergedwst)
       mergedord2<-as.matrix(mergedord)



       ht_global_opt(heatmap_legend_title_gp = gpar(fontsize = 6, fontface = "bold"), 
                     heatmap_legend_labels_gp = gpar(fontsize = 6), heatmap_column_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 6))


       ht1<-Heatmap(merged2, 
               show_row_dend = FALSE,
               show_column_dend = FALSE,
            show_row_names = FALSE,
             column_names_side = "top",
            column_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 8),
        cluster_rows = FALSE, 
        cluster_columns = FALSE,
                name = "# I,# E,# S,# R", cell_fun = function(j, i, x, y, width, height, fill) 
               {
                 grid.text(sprintf("%.0f", merged2[i, j]), x, y, gp = gpar(fontsize = 8))
               },
            col = colorRamp2(c(0, max_merged), c(rgb(200/255, 202/255, 201/255),rgb(116/255, 122/255, 119/255))))

       ht2<-Heatmap(mergedvc2, 
               show_row_dend = FALSE,
               show_column_dend = FALSE,
            row_names_side = "left",
             column_names_side = "top",
            column_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 8),
             row_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 8),
         cluster_rows = FALSE, 
        cluster_columns = FALSE,
                name = "# V", cell_fun = function(j, i, x, y, width, height, fill) 
               {
                 grid.text(sprintf("%.0f", mergedvc2[i, j]), x, y, gp = gpar(fontsize = 8))
               },
            col = colorRamp2(c(0, max_mergedvc), c(rgb(185/255, 221/255, 141/255),rgb(119/255, 188/255, 31/255))))

       ht3<-Heatmap(mergedwst2, 
       show_row_dend = FALSE,
       show_column_dend = FALSE,
       show_row_names = FALSE,
        column_names_side = "top",
       column_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 8),
    uster_rows = FALSE, 
    uster_columns = FALSE,

           name = "% W", cell_fun = function(j, i, x, y, width, height, fill) 
       {
         grid.text(sprintf("%.0f", mergedwst2[i, j]), x, y, gp = gpar(fontsize = 8))
       },
       col = colorRamp2(c(0,max_mergedwst), c( rgb(236/255, 154/255, 169/255),rgb(217/255, 59/255, 86/255))))

       ht4<-Heatmap(mergedord2, 
       show_row_dend = FALSE,
       show_column_dend = FALSE,
       show_row_names = FALSE,
        column_names_side = "top",
        column_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 8),
    uster_rows = FALSE, 
    uster_columns = FALSE,

           name = "# O", cell_fun = function(j, i, x, y, width, height, fill) 
       {
         grid.text(sprintf("%.0f", mergedord2[i, j]), x, y, gp = gpar(fontsize = 8))
       },

       col = colorRamp2(c(0,max_mergedord), c( rgb(255/255, 207/255, 176/255),rgb(255/255, 108/255, 12/255))))

       ht_list<-ht2+ht4+ht1+ht3

       draw(ht_list, gap = unit(0, "cm"))
```